# how to change several piece of html code

Tags: bash, text-processing, python, perl

I have several chunks of html code ,see below, in a html page that I need to change

```
Assurez-vous de bien recevoir tous nos messages en ajoutant bebeco@concretisezvosprojets.com à votre carnet d'adresses.<br />
Si vous avez des difficultés pour visualiser ce message, rendez-vous sur
```

to

```
[{headerbebeco}]
```

or

```
http://www.bebeco.fr
```

to

```
http://mm.eulerian.net/dynclick/bebeco/?eml-publisher=bebeco&eml-name=deme_faible&eemail={email}&eurl=https://www.bebeco.fr/?utm_source=ANIM&utm_medium=Targeting&utm_campaign=deme_faible&utm_term=CCCC_seg_men&utm_content=website
```

One possible thing to do is to change every part of it by hand with stuff like notepad.

As you can imagine, lots of stumble, mistakes and hair pulling.

One other possible is to automatize it with tools like sed or awk.

I came out with these 2 lines.

```
awk -v old="Assurez-vous de bien recevoir tous nos messages en ajoutant      bebeco@cab05.net a votre carnet d'adresses.<br />
 Si vous avez des difficult&eacute;s pour visualiser ce message, rendez-vous sur " -v   new="[{headerbebeco}]" 's=index($0,old){$0=substr($0,1,s-1) new   substr($0,s+length(old))}1' test_bebeco_v2.html > tmp && mv tmp test_bebeco_v2.html

sed -i 's~Assurez-vous de bien recevoir tous nos messages en ajoutant bebeco@cab05.net a votre carnet d'adresses.<br /> Si vous avez des difficult&eacute;s pour visualiser ce message, rendez-vous sur~[{headerbebeco}]~g' test_Sofinco_v2.html
```

But none of these lines , either in awk or sed are satisfactory e.g. it is not doing the replacements I'm trying to do.

I'm wondering if there are tools where I can do that either by programming it. Bash seems to be compromised but if you have another solutions in python or in bash or just a program, I'm willing to listen.

Cheers.

**update : sample below**

Assurez-vous de bien recevoir tous nos messages en ajoutant bebeco@cab05.net a votre carnet d'adresses.
Si vous avez des difficultés pour visualiser ce message, rendez-vous sur

Answer (score 1):

`Sed` or `awk` are **one**-line editors. You have to join two lines in one or use options (exist in `GNU sed` versions > 4.2.1)

```
sed -zi 's~Assurez-vous de bien recevoir tous nos messages en ajoutant bebeco@cab05\.net a votre carnet d'\''adresses.<br />\n Si vous avez des difficult\\&eacute;s pour visualiser ce message, rendez-vous sur~[{headerbebeco}]~g' test_Sofinco_v2.html
```

But in most cases you have not put all string as pattern, some times a few words is enough:

```
sed -i '/^Assurez-vous de bien/{N; /rendez-vous sur$/s/.*/[{headerbebeco}]/}' test_Sofinco_v2.html
```

or

```
sed -i '/^Assurez-vous de bien/d;/Si vous avez des difficultés pour visualiser ce message, rendez-vous sur/s//[{headerbebeco}]/}' test_Sofinco_v2.html
```

Comment: `sed -z 's~Assurez-vous de bien recevoir tous nos messages en ajoutant bebeco@concretisezvosprojets.com à votre carnet d'\''adresses.<br />\nSi vous avez des difficultés pour visualiser ce message, rendez-vous sur~[{headerbebeco}]~'`

Comment: ah see @Costas! You need to play down the spaces and you need to put the \n for going to next line. All I'm trying is to simplify everything, to do a copy and paste of the strings and voilà.

Comment: Compare to beforehand `à`,`é` symbols instead usual `a` and `\\&eacute;` and extra space on beginning of second line.

Comment: I got your point , @Costas. Not sure why I do not have the `à` in clear. But the point is I need to be able change the strings ,with the space or the line feed.

Comment: `à` is not a main problem. To cut|paste work try to choice 1 line (or its part) to substitute, second (and other) to delete.

Comment: Going crazy. One of the guy I'm working with, is doing that by hand... Not my style...